# python - cut a string in 2 lines

Tags: python, string

I'm looking for a line (using `str.join` I think) to cut a long string if the number of word is too much. I have the begining but I don't know whow to insert `\n`

```
example = "Au Fil Des Antilles De La Martinique a Saint Barthelemy"

nmbr_word =  len(example.split(" "))
if nmbr_word >= 6:
   # cut the string to have

result = "Au Fil Des Antilles De La\nMartinique a Saint Barthelemy"
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module.  It can wrap text to fit into a certain amount of characters (rather than a certain amount of words), but it might be relevant to your use case anyway.

Comment: `str = ...` is a bad idea! Don't use preexisting identifiers as names. Also you don't need the parenthesis around `len` when defining `nmbr_word`.

Comment: Ok, I will modify my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the [`textwrap` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html)?

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> s  = "Au Fil Des Antilles De La Martinique a Saint Barthelemy"
>>> textwrap.wrap(s, 30)
['Au Fil Des Antilles De La', 'Martinique a Saint Barthelemy']
>>> "\n".join(textwrap.wrap(s, 30))
'Au Fil Des Antilles De La\nMartinique a Saint Barthelemy'
```

Comment: The split should be conducted by word number, not by width.

Comment: Thanks, what is `30` means ?

Comment: It's the number of characters that must not be exceeded  per line. As @RobbieLiu noted, that's not exactly what you asked for, but perhaps it's still useful (maybe even more so than splitting per number of words...)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
'\n'.join([' '.join(nmbr_word[i:i+6]) for i in xrange(0, len(nmbr_word), 6)])
```